# How to produce javax.faces.ViewState hidden field without 'id' and 'autocomplete' attributes

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets, viewstate, mojarra

This is what I have in the output HTML document (produced by JSF 2.0/Mojarra 2.0.3):

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" 
id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="4267906931114993858:-6309146738430577631"
autocomplete="off" />
```

My document should be `XHTML 1.1` compliant, where attribute `autocomplete` is not valid and `id` attribute is duplicated over all forms. How to instruct JSF to produce everything strictly compliant to XHTML?

Comment: There is no such thing as XHTML 1.1 strict. XHTML 1.0 has Strict, Transitional and Frameset variants. XHTML 1.1 is just XHTML 1.1

Comment: @David thanks, I corrected my question

Answer (score 3):

See.

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.autoCompleteOffOnViewState</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableViewStateIdRendering</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Answer (score 2):

The non unique use if the ID javax.faces.ViewState is a bug that appears Oracle will not fix. They have closed these tickets.  No workaround.

Comment: Last one is still open and targeted for 2.2: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1699

Answer (score 1):

> How to instruct JSF to produce
>   everything strictly compliant to
>   XHTML?

That's not a matter of "instructing" the JSF implementation with a simple flag. It's something that has to be continuously checked and thus only possible when it's considered important by the project. XHTML strict imposes a lot of restrictions and is probably therefore generally not considered worth supporting - see [this bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-404). Note also that any component library you use *also* has to support it.

You'll have a lot more luck with XHTML 1.0 Transitional - I can confirm that MyFaces does produce valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional (once you set the context param org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID to false).

Comment: Transitional isn't going to help — `autocomplete` is not in any XHTML 1.x

Comment: @David: True. But even if you get rid of that, there are quite a lot of other things that all JSF implementations I know produce that are not XHTML Strict compliant.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this problem, it was created in version 1.2_14 of JSF. I think the problem is related to the way that Firefox operates during the reset event (input type=reset) on hidden fields. There is a problem where the client viewState that is on a hidden field gets an inconsistent state. The solution for this problem was disabled the auto-complete in a strict way (and this is not XHTML compliant). The most interesting thing is that until 1.2_14 almost everybody lived with this potential error. So the JSF-RI implementation (Mojarra project) allowed a developer to disable this option using a parameter that you can edit in your web.xml, and this auto complete won't print anymore.

```
<context-param>
    <description>Put your description here :)</description>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.autoCompleteOffOnViewState</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It is really difficult to produce valid XHTML pages with component based frameworks like JSF, but at least a solution exists for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to disable `autocomplete="off"` for ViewState hidden input fields, because then Firefox doesn't refresh the ViewState-Id on page refresh. This causes unusable JSF forms and functionalities.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460909/firefox-overrides-javax-faces-viewstate-with-old-value-on-f5-how-to-turn-off-au) post for details.